# ignore case in php

Tags: php, arrays

i am searching a text using in_array() function from the array which is fetching database value

$value is the array value.

How can i ignore case in this.

```
if(in_array($exp[$i],$value))
```

Comment: Are you asking for the case when `$exp[$i]` does not exists in `$array` ?

Comment: Are you testing a single element of the array? Your current code implies so. In which case, `in_array()` is not the right function to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) instead:

```
if( preg_grep( "/" . $exp [$i] . "/i" , $value ) )
```

(the `i` modifier added after the `/` makes it case insensitive)

However, since it seems it isn't an array value, you shouldn't be using [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), but [stristr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php):

```
if ( stristr ($value, $exp [$i]))
```

([stristr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) is the case insensitive version of [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), which finds the first occurrence of a string in another string)

Comment: I'm pretty sure preg_grep is case-sensitive.

Comment: Not when you add the `i` modifier ;)

Comment: You are correct, though that is not clear with the preg_grep() man page. It is covered [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php)

Comment: Added short explanation to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to all upper/lower case in the comparison

```
if(in_array($exp[$i], strtoupper($value)))
```

EDIT: I'm guessing that this $exp[$i] will also need to be case agnostic, so then

```
if(in_array(strtoupper($exp[$i]), strtoupper($value)))
```

Comment: but from database it's coming like Mysql,DRUPAL,java.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.